# Can make angular2+ or vue.js or the latest version of react.js support es3 browser via typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Currently, I have a project like to use the react.js ,but the latest version of react.js do not support the ie8 and my company may can not abandon the ie8's user.
So can I use `typescript` to make the react.js support the es3 browser?

Comment: [The React developers no longer fix IE8-related bugs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2016/01/12/discontinuing-ie8-support.html). Even if you compile your code down to a syntax that IE8 can understand, your experience is likely to be poor. Unless you have corporate clients that refuse to upgrade their browser (in which case - my condolences), you should just not bother supporting IE8. It's no longer supported by Microsoft, and only 0.29% of users still use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript *can* compile down to ES3, but you're going to be losing a lot of features and very possibly get some invisible errors. Even compiling down to ES5 can cause issues with things like `IterableIterators` not functioning properly. On top of that, as far as I'm aware, none of those front ends will ever support IE8. Even AngularJS had difficulty with supporting IE8.

Comment: One question: The vue and angular2's core function is  `Object.defineproperty()`,  are you mean that there some new function in es5/6 like that may not be completely support by the typescript or babel?

Comment: I personally ran into issues using `Map` and non-Arraylike `IterableIterators`. I was having a `for-of` loop that compiled perfectly fine into ES5 fail because of some weirdness with `entries()` and down-level iteration. On top of that ES3 doesn't include getters, setters, or any of the Array functional methods which I believe Angular uses heavily. [Here's Angular's Browser Support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)].